Formatting chapters in the toc in memoir
Good evening,
to meet the requirements of my university, I got to do some changes to the way chapters are displayed in the Toc. I read the corresponding memoir documentation but couldn't figure how to achieve this. I got three problems :

The word "chapitre" and the chapter number have to be in roman, the title in italic. The best I can get is to have "chapter" in roman and the chapter number and the title in italic.
For the \chapter(s)*, I can't get rid of the colon ; ideally, the title of those chapters should be aligned with the word "Chapitre" for the normal chapters.
For the appendices, I should display the word "Annexe" before the letter (where "Chapitre" is for the others chapters), as in the main text.

Here a MWE :
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{memoir}

\usepackage[polutonikogreek,french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{verbatim}



\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}

\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\small \normalfont \emph}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{\small \normalfont} 
\renewcommand*{\cftchaptername}{\scshape \emph{Chapitre} \space}
\renewcommand{\cftchapteraftersnum}{ \emph{:} \emph{\space}}

\setlength{\cftchapterindent}{0.5cm}
\setlength{\cftchapternumwidth}{0.8cm}
\setlength{\cftbeforechapterskip}{6pt}
   
\setlength{\cftsectionindent}{1cm}
\setlength{\cftsectionnumwidth}{0.6cm}


%This shouldn't have much to do with the problem, I leave it just in case
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\center}{\bsc{Chapitre} \thechapter}{28pt}{\bfseries}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{56pt}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]
  {\normalfont}{\thesection}{10pt}{\bfseries}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{14pt}{7pt}

 \renewcommand*{\cftsectionfont}{\small \normalfont}
 \renewcommand*{\cftsectionpagefont}{\small \normalfont}
 \renewcommand{\cftsectionleader}{\normalfont\cftdotfill{\cftsectiondotsep}}
 \renewcommand*{\cftsectiondotsep}{0.2}
 \renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}.}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*

\chapter*{Introduction générale}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}\scshape \emph{Introduction générale}}
\section*{Choix des auteurs}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}Choix des auteurs}
\section*{Choix du corpus}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}Choix du corpus}


\chapter{Mariage et formation dans le \emph{De Sacramentis}}
\section{Le mariage avant l'histoire}
\section{L'exégèse de Gn 1, 1-2}

\chapter*{Conclusion générale}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}\scshape \emph{Conclusion générale}}


\appendix
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\center}{\bsc{Annexe} \thechapter}{28pt}{\bfseries}
  
\chapter{Bilan des différences entre les éditions du \emph{De Sacramentis} dans la \emph{Patrologia latina} et dans le \emph{Corpus Victorinum}}
\end{document}

I tried this for the first problem but got a bunch of error messages :
\renewcommand{\chapternumberline}[1]{\emph{\bsc{Chapitre}} \emph{\Roman #1} \emph{:} }
The problems are quite obvious here I guess :

Thank you very much for any help !

First of, do not use titlesec with memoir, they are not compatible.

And never put punctuation at the end of \thesection etc, it does not belong there and other macros does not expect it.

I've removed everything titlesec so any formating of the chapters has to be done using memoir tools.
This seems to do what you asked. I removed small caps as it was not in the requirement. I also removed . at the end of the definition of \thesection as it does not belong there.
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{memoir}

\usepackage[polutonikogreek,french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{verbatim}



\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}

\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\small \normalfont \emph}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{\small \normalfont} 
\renewcommand*{\cftchaptername}{\chaptername\space}
\renewcommand*{\cftappendixname}{\appendixname\space}
\renewcommand{\cftchapteraftersnum}{{:}\space}

\setlength{\cftchapterindent}{0cm}
\setlength{\cftchapternumwidth}{2em}
\setlength{\cftbeforechapterskip}{6pt}
   
\setlength{\cftsectionindent}{1cm}
\setlength{\cftsectionnumwidth}{0.6cm}


% it looks best if the title indent in chapters and appendix align,
% but they differ in widths so we cheat.
\newlength\foobar
\ExplSyntaxOn
\hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box {\cftchapterfont\chaptername~III}
\hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpb_box {\cftchapterfont\appendixname~M}
\dim_set:Nn \foobar { \dim_max:nn{\box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box}{\box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

% spacing between the common size and the start of the text
\addtolength\foobar{1cm}



\renewcommand*{\cftsectionfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand*{\cftsectionpagefont}{\small \normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsectionleader}{\normalfont\cftdotfill{\cftsectiondotsep}}
\renewcommand*{\cftsectiondotsep}{0.2}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\makeatletter
% this can be ised to mnove the \addcontentsline chapter* in without the :
\DeclareRobustCommand{\altchapternumberline}[1]{%
  \chapternumberlinebox\@tempdima{\phantom{\@chapapp@head\@cftbsnum #1\@cftasnum}}%
}
% redefine the normal chapternumberline, to reset the font
\DeclareRobustCommand{\chapternumberline}[1]{%
  \chapternumberlinehook{#1}%
  \chapternumberlinebox\@tempdima{{\normalfont\@chapapp@head\@cftbsnum #1\@cftasnum}}%
  \@cftasnumb}

% mess with chapter and chapter entries in toc, to use a common size for the both with the chapter name and number
\xpatchcmd\l@chapapp{\addtolength{\@tempdima}{\cftchapternumwidth}}%
{\setlength{\@tempdima}{\foobar}}{}{\typeout{failed}}


\makeatother


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*

\chapter*{Introduction générale}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction générale}
\section*{Choix des auteurs}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\numberline{}Choix des auteurs}
\section*{Choix du corpus}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\numberline{}Choix du corpus}


\chapter{Mariage et formation dans le \emph{De Sacramentis}}
\section{Le mariage avant l'histoire}
\section{L'exégèse de Gn 1, 1-2}

\chapter*{Conclusion générale}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Conclusion générale}


\appendix
  
\chapter{Bilan des différences entre les éditions du \emph{De Sacramentis} dans la \emph{Patrologia latina} et dans le \emph{Corpus Victorinum}}
\end{document}


OK thank you so much, it's really really great! I'll look at it in detail as soon as I'm back home later in the day to see if I understand what you did. Thank you again!!

Okay it's really perfect. Thank you so much. I would never have know that titlesec and memoir are not compatible. I think the "ExpSyntax" block and the two last blocks are definitely out of my reach but the result is exactly what is required. Thank you for the quick and helpful answer.

@Greg have a look in interface3.pdf. I was just lazy and needed a way of getting the larges of two lengths. You can of course do that manually using some if statements. Regadring titlesec among others is does not (to my knowledge) support the dual optional args for chapter and friends that memoir does.

I wish I could be lazy the way you are ! I will check this out, thank you so much one again

@Greg I litteraly just started with expl3 this spring after avoiding it for years. Cannot deny that it makes a lot of things much easier.
